# Стоит ли использовать get_magic_quotes_gpc() в данном случае?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, mariadb

В моей книге (Создаем динамические веб-сайты с помощью PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, CSS и HTML5) есть пример обработки данных, которые ввел пользователь перед занесением их в БД.

```
function mysql_fix_string($conn, $string) {
   if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $string = stripslashes($string);
   return $conn->real_escape_string($string);
}
```

По словам автора, get_magic_quotes_gpc() проверяет включено ли свойство "волшебных кавычек", экранирующее кавычки в строке. Если функция возвращает TRUE, то тогда срабатывает функция stripslashes, которая вырезает из строки слэши (убирает экранирование), чтобы real_escape_string() не экранировала кавычки дважды.
Но в документации написано, что get_magic_quotes_gpc() является устаревшей еще с версии PHP 5.4.0. и всегда возвращает FALSE. Да и сам автор говорит, что свойство magic_quotes, которое автоматически экранирует одиночные и двойные кавычки было удалено начиная с PHP 5.4.0.

**Есть ли смысл использовать get_magic_quotes_gpc()?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Только если вам необходимо обеспечивать работу этого кода на музейных версиях PHP, как вы верно нашли, до PHP 5.4.0.

Если же ваш проект будет требовать более современные версии PHP - то вам эта проверка  не нужна и можете эту историческую ошибку с введением магических ошибок не учитывать.

---

Смотря на функцию целиком - она вам не нужна вся целиком. Используйте API `prepared statements` вместо ручного экранирования значений.